# WPF Making the ListView Height the same as the Grid row height

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, data-binding

I want to data bind the height of a row in a grid to the height of my ListView. Sadly I can't make the DataBinding work. The ListView is inside the Grid. Any help is very welcome :)

Those are some snippets of my xaml code:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" Name="rowDefenitionOne"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, 
ElementName=rowDefenitionOne}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
....
</ListView>
```

Comment: If the row is `auto` and the `ListView` is `VerticalAlignment=Stretch` (the default), then why doesn't this take care of itself?

Comment: Is this `Grid` only control in the screen?

Comment: try `x:Name` instead of `Name`

Comment: yes, the root elemt after window is grid

Comment: changing the name to x:name also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the row height to follow the height of the children (only a single child here ListView). The row height will follow the height of that ListView.

> Making the ListView Height the same as the Grid row height

Well, *the ListView Height **is** the same as the Grid row height*

I guess that is not what you are looking for.

With that

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    ....
</ListView>
```

the grid row will take all the possible height and the ListView will follow that row height.